# is there a way to edit all reference highlights in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cursor-position

Usually in vs2015 and vs2017 (at least) when you select a word, automatically all the references of the word get selected. I would like to know if there is a way to edit all the occurrences using a keyboard shortcut (placing multiple cursors without the searching dialog), as an example, let's say that in the image below i would like to replace the "Some" with "Very".

[image: Reference Higlighting]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx

Comment: Press `F2` to rename something.

Comment: @solarc thank you! Your answer is what actually wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking your reference, then choosing "Rename..."

Answer (score 1):

**Update for VS 2022.**
You're going to want to make use of VS2022's Multiple Caret functionality if you're not strickly looking to perform a variable/function rename action, which can be done using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Once you've made the initial selection you can use `Edit -> Multiple Carets -> Insert Carets At All Matching` functionality.

By default, this function is mapped to: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

This will add a new caret to each of the highlighted/matching sections allowing you to edit them simultaneously.

Multi-caret support in VS2022 is quite extensive. [You can explore more options in the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022#multi-caret-selection)

Comment: thanks a lot you are a real necromancer! This can also be done in VS Code with Ctrl+D

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one plug-in, [Multi Edit Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode), but you can just modify the function name and use the light bulb/quick actions (`Ctrl .`) to rename/refactor all references to the function.